# What are the limitations of developing flash in command line with Flex SDK?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, command-line, sdk

A few days ago, I began to develop a flash with text editor and Flex SDK which is free.
But I found Flex SDK doesn't support Alert or Scrollbar.
What are the differences between `Flex SDK` and `Flash Professional or Builder`?
Are there any other limitations of developing flash in command line with Flex SDK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All what you can do with Flash Builder, you can perform with Flex SDK from the command line. Because of Flash Builder hasn't any own compiler but uses Flex SDK. So in case of some components in your project are unavailable the problem can be in wron configuration (I mean command line parameters).

I can recommend you not to use `mxmlc` directly but take advantage of [Apache Maven with Flex Mojos](http://flexmojos.sonatype.org/) or Apache Ant.

Also if you're on Windows you can use [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/) which is free.

What about Flash Professional it has some animation features etc which can be used by designers, animators etc. It doesn't use Flex SDK at all.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... that's strange because Alert and ScrollBar should be part of the free Flex SDK. Normally, all that's missing are the chart UI components (pie chart, bar chart, etc.). Maybe you forgot to link to some library when you compiled your code?

Flash Professional and Flash Builder both use the Flex SDK. The first one is mainly for designers, while the second one is more for programmers and for the creation of user interfaces. Basically, if you can code with a text editor, you don't need either of those.

Comment: Two notes. First, charting components are free and part of Flex SDK since 3.5. Second, Flash Professional has its own compiler and doesn't use Flex SDK at all.

Comment: I just checked my version of Flash CS4 and I see that the Flex SDK is shipped with it so it does use it (or, at least, it *can* use it provided that you add the import statements to your code). As for compiling, I don't know what it uses (and wasn't commenting on that).

Comment: Flash Professional includes some parts of Flex SDK. The main goal of it is take possibility to interpret metatags (like `[Embed]` etc) correctly. It doesn't use Flex compiler. More details are [here](http://actionscriptexamples.com/2008/10/26/using-the-flex-sdk-with-flash-cs4/) and [here](http://flashauthoring.blogspot.com/search?updated-max=2008-10-23T20%3A46%3A00-07%3A00&max-results=1).